# How to get arraylist inside arraylist where index = x

Tags: html, angularjs

Good day, this is my first time asking here at stack overflow so pardon for the mistakes that you will see in my question.

im new at web programming and angular. 
i created a list of prescription and inside the prescription there are list of medicines

```
.controller('prescriptionTable',function($scope) {
var Prescription = [
    {id:1,secID:1,docID:1,medicine:[
        {name:"lozartan",quantity:2},
        {name:"biogesic",quantity:3},
        {name:"paracetamol",quantity:1},]
    },
    {id:2,secID:1,docID:1,medicine:[
        {name:"Lumiracoxib",quantity:2},
        {name:"Cloxacillin",quantity:3},
        {name:"Allopurinol",quantity:4}]
    },
];

$scope.Prescription = Prescription;
$scope.indexNum =0;
```

then i use ng-repeat so i can get the list of medicines

```
<div ng-controller="prescriptionTable">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="px in Prescription">
            {{px.id}}
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="med in px.medicine">
                    Name: {{med.name}} , Quantity: {{med.quantity}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I filter the Prescription to show only the list of medicines of a certain prescription using $scope.indexNum?

thanks and cheers.

Comment: from where you generating $scope.indexNum and on which basis you enerating this index and how?Is there any html?

Comment: im planning to have a <input> to get the prescription ID inside the html

Comment: I think that the best way to do this is using  filters. For example: `med in px.medicine | filter:indexNum track by med.quantity` . I tried to give you a plunker but I don't know why is not working now. look the ng-repeat (docs)[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat], here it is explicated better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you only want to allow a single index you could specify it either as

```
$scope.indexNum = 0;
```

and in your html

```
<li ng-repeat="px in Prescription track by $index" ng-if="$index == indexNum">
```

OR

you may even hard code a value `0`

```
<li ng-repeat="px in Prescription track by $index" ng-if="$index == 0">
```

OR

if you only want to display one item, you should avoid `ng-repeat` altogether

```
<div ng-controller="prescriptionTable">
    <ul>
        <li>
            {{Prescription[indexNum].id}}
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="med in Prescription[indexNum].medicine">
                Name: {{med.name}} , Quantity: {{med.quantity}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

OR

you can have multiple index as

```
<div ng-controller="prescriptionTable">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="px in Prescription track by $index" ng-if="allowedIndexes.indexOf($index) > -1">
            {{px.id}}
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="med in px.medicine">
                    Name: {{med.name}} , Quantity: {{med.quantity}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and in your `js` you will have an array as

```
$scope.allowedIndexes = [0,2,5,7,9];
```

OR

you can use angular filter

```
<div ng-controller="prescriptionTable">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="px in Prescription|filter:{id:indexNum}">
            {{px.id}}
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="med in px.medicine">
                    Name: {{med.name}} , Quantity: {{med.quantity}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This will filter all objects with `id` containing value of `indexNum`, that is if `indexNum` is 1, then there will be objects with `id` equal 1, 10, 11, 12, 21... displayed.

Comment: Thanks. The track solve the problem. do you have some tutorials where i can learn more angular and html? thanks again for the help.

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials available online. You could potentially start at http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/beginner2expert-how_to_start.html.